# sql select all after specific string

Tags: mysql

Suppose i have a string " one , two , three , four , five". How can i select everything after substring "three" without the following comma in order to have as  a result string " four , five"; Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on the database, please specify which one you are using.

Comment: Google "String Functions" for the database software you are using.

Comment: Why do you store data like comma separated items? It will only cause you lots of problems...

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I will remove comma's . But problem remains

Answer (score 0):

(For MySQL :)

Use :

```
 SUBSTR(your_string, index_begin, index_end).
```

In your example, it should be

```
 SUBSTR(" one , two , three , four , five", 22)
```

(if you don't give any index_end, it will take the string till the end)

Comment: SUBSTR is product specific, and no dbms specified (yet). Also, the problem also seems to include how to find the item.

Comment: My string is constructed dynamically ( arrayList). So i don't know index_begin and index_end

Comment: You can try SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, count) to get the index_begin